# How to require X.509 certificate authentication in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, authentication, x509certificate

There's plenty of material on how to authenticate using an X.509 certificate via `HttpWebRequest` from the *client side*, but no certificate is actually sent because the server does issue the challenge to the client to send it.  How can I configure an ASP.NET MVC site to require an X.509 client certificate for certain MVC actions?

Note, I've seen X.509 client auth configurations in IIS, but I don't want to *always* require X.509 -- just on certain actions.

Comment: I've got the same question.  Any progress on this?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIAA, HTTPS handshake is always handled by IIS/Windows, you do not control it from your application. The only possible way is to have a specially configured part of your application which is set to require client certificate, and the rest without it. Then, when you want the user to submit his/her certificate, redirect them to that page in the special part (which will probably just store/validate the received certificate and redirect back).